# HTML: How do I remove hyperlink underline from an Image and text?

Tags: html, css

After adding some hyperlinks to an Image, it has the underline but I couldn't find a way to remove it. First I tried `text-decoration: none;` but I noticed it only works for text, so the image looks like
[this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6lrx.png)

The "Claro" image has that underline that I cannot remove.

Here is the code:

```css
* {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

#parte1 {
  background-color: #da291c;
}

#parte2 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 480px 10px 0px;
}

#parte3 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin: 10px 480px 10px 0px;
}

#logo {
  background-color: #da291c;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#parte1-samsung {
  background-color: #da291c;
}

#parte2-samsung {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 480px 10px 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>Caracteristicas Claro</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div id="parte1" class="container">
      <a href="https://tiendaclaro.pe" title="Tienda Claro">
        <img src="https://placehold.jp/200x100.png" alt="Claro" height="50" id="logo" />
      </a>
    </div>
  </center>

  <div id="parte2" class="container">
    <a href="Web Claro.html" title="Inicio" id="reinicio">Inicio</a>

    <a href="equipos-samsung.html" title="Samsung" target="_blank" id="resamsung">Samsung</a>
  </div>
  <div id="parte3">Aqui iran el equipo y sus caracteristicas</div>
</body>

</html>
```

How do I manage to erase that underline of the image and make the other "Inicio" and "Samsung" options to looks like normal text, instead of that purple or blue color?

Comment: Please note the `center` tag and inline styling attribute like `height` or `width` have been deprecated since the early 2000s, consider using something more modern and valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're referring to as underline is not actually underline.

You've added this line in your CSS

```
* {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}
```

that means every HTML tag will have this background. so your image and parent `<a>` will also have this background color and since the image has a bottom margin this which makes a gap in parent `<a>` and this gap is filled with the defined background color.

so what you're seeing is a filled background color, not **an underline or border**.

Answer (score 0):

if you set background-color:#colorname; within body element selector like.

```
body {
       background-color:#colorname;
     }
```

That means set background colour #colorname; of your body.

But When you will use this css property into universal selector like.

```
* {
    background-color:#colorname;
  }
```

that means set background color #colorname of all element of the web page.

I hope it is helpful for you.

```
     * {}
body{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

#parte1 {
  background-color: #da291c;
}

#parte2 {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 480px 10px 0px;
}

#parte3 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  margin: 10px 480px 10px 0px;
}

#logo {
  background-color: #da291c;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#parte1-samsung {
  background-color: #da291c;
}

#parte2-samsung {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 480px 10px 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the background-color: #eeeeee; property to the body tag instead of *

```css
body{
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}
#parte1{
    background-color: #da291c;
}
#parte2{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px 480px 10px 0px;
}
#parte3{
    background-color: blueviolet;
    margin: 10px 480px 10px 0px;
}
#logo{    
    background-color:  #da291c;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#parte1-samsung{
    background-color: #da291c;
}
#parte2-samsung{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px 480px 10px 0px;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Caracteristicas Claro</title>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <div id="parte1" class="container">
        <a href="https://tiendaclaro.pe" title="Tienda Claro"><img src="icons/LogoClaro.png" alt="Claro" height="50" id="logo"></a>
    </div>
    </center>
    <div id="parte2" class="container">
        <a  href="Web Claro.html" title="Inicio"  id="reinicio">Inicio</a>
        <a  href="equipos-samsung.html" title="Samsung" target="_blank" id="resamsung">Samsung</a>      
    </div>
    <div id="parte3">
        Aqui iran el equipo y sus caracteristicas
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```